# command substitution before ssh

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, zsh

I want to write the results from a job into a remote file on another host in my cluster. I know I can do this:

```
echo 'My text' | ssh me@my.host "cat >> ~/my.output"
```

which will append 'My text' to the remote file just fine. But let's say I am on `my.node` and I want to write this result to a file on `my.host`:

```
echo "`hostname`:My text" | ssh me@my.host "cat >> ~/my.output"
```

And I expect to see **`my.node:My text`** in `~/my.output` on `my.host`. But what I actually see is this: **`my.host:My text`**.

**How can I get the value of `hostname` substituted before the `ssh` command? Is it possible? I also tried this:**

```
echo "$(hostname):My text" | ssh me@my.host "cat >> ~/test.output"
```

Comment: This should work as you expect. What does `echo "$(hostname):My text"` print to your (local) terminal?

Comment: @mpy as always, it helps to make a *complete* example of your problem, not just the subset which you *think* is the cause of your problem. In my case, I was sending a script to be run on the remote computer by means of a `heredoc`. By not quoting the `heredoc` delimiter my shell was expanding variables before the contents of the script were run on the remote machine. Your commented prompted me to  think about that aspect so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want is to run a local script remotely.

Of course, you can do the following:

```sh
ssh me@my.host 'echo "$(hostname):My text" >> ~/test.output'
```

But you can also move that code to a script file and do this:

```sh
ssh me@my.host < myscript.sh
```

And inside *myscript.sh*:

```sh
echo "$(hostname):My text" >> ~/test.output
```

If you don't want to put the stdout redirection inside the script, you can add it before piping the ssh client. For example:

```sh
cat myscript.sh | sed '1iexec >> ~/test.output' | ssh me@my.host
```

This adds the stdout redirection to the first line of the script (`1i`). Use `2i` if you have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Thanks, for attempting, but it's not quite my scenario. In my scenario I am running a job script via `qsub` on a remote host. So the remote host is happily executing the commands in the script. At some point I want that remote host to write some information into a file back on my submit host (or some other remote location relative to itself). The reason for using ssh is that I have set-up passwordless ssh access between all hosts in my cluster.